# Ищем оптимальный модуль для сайта по каталогизации

Tags: массивы, база-данных, сортировка, поиск-библиотек

Поставлена задача провести каталогизацию большого массива картин по разным параметрам (художник, стиль, год, галерея и т.п.) на публичном сайте. Необходим модуль, в котором есть удобная форма внесения этих данных вручную разными людьми удаленно. Модуль должен быть достаточно простой и удобный для постинга не профессиональных контент-менеджеров (в идеале - не сложнее чем постинг в соцсетях). Рассматривали wiki-движок, но по отзывам - сложно заводить контент.

Вопрос №1: есть ли какой то готовый модуль или программа которые оптимально подходят для такой задачи? Если нет, то на каком языке такой лучше написать? Пробовали использовать модуль для интернет магазина но много лишних атрибутов (цена, доставка, скидки и т.п.).

Под этот процесс планируется создать отдельный сайт “с нуля”, поэтому
Вопрос №2: какой движок сайта/фреймворк лучше подходит для такого модуля?
Пробовали коробочный сайт (ucoz) но в нем существенные системные ограничения.

P.S. Если кто то знает хорошего специалиста по таким задачам - порекомендуйте.
Если вопрос не для этого ресурса - подскажите в какой лучше написать.

Comment: Не проще ли в гугль таблицах заполнять.

Comment: Excel наше все.

Comment: лучше нанять знающего человека, который сделает решение по вашим требованиям. по факту вопрос не для данного ресурса

Comment: Кстати, да, проще было бы разослать всем шаблонный Excel файл, пусть заполняют и отсылают обратно. А потом это всё можно разобрать довольно просто хоть на питоне хоть на других языках.